# How to apply css rules to html element using ExtJS?

Tags: css, extjs4, opacity

I am drawing an image inside panel and slider field using **ExtJS 4**. I want to change opacity of image whenever of value of slider field changes.

I am aware that `opacity` and `filter:alpha(opacity=);` rule of CSS can be applied to image which will change its opacity.

However I do not know how to apply this css rule to the image. Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Ext.dom.Element.setOpacity](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-setOpacity) method:

```
Ext.fly('image-id').setOpacity(0.5); // this will make img with id 'image-id' become half-transparent
```

Here is [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/Af3Rt/)

### Update

If you are using [Ext.Img component](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Img) you will have to do something like the following:

```
imgCmp.getEl().setOpacity(0.5);
```